# How to format data for one-way intraclass correlation coefficient?

Tags: reliability, agreement-statistics, intraclass-correlation

I'm testing inter-rater reliability of an instrument on a sample of subjects from several sites. Each subject is assessed by two raters, different between each site.

According to [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4913118/), I should use one-way ICC, which is used when subjects are rated by a different set of raters. It's not clear to me what the data should look like in this case. Python and R ICC libraries don't accept 'incomplete' dataset (where some raters did not rate some subjects).

Should I replace unique rater IDs with a generic rater count, where every subject is rated by "Rater 1" and "Rater 2", which don't correspond to specific raters? Or did I misunderstand what one-way ICC is used for?

Comment: What you suggest in your last paragraph - two columns named "rater 1" and "rater 2" and one row per participant - is what I've always done in a similar situation, I sincerely hope it's correct.